# How can I search into two columns and sort the result by priority?

Tags: mysql, sql, search-engine

I have a table like this:

```
-- users
+----+------------+-------------+
| id | first_name |  last_name  |
+----+------------+-------------+
| 1  | John       | Kooper      |
| 2  | Martin     | Koop        |
| 3  | Koop       | Sth         |
| 4  | Jack       | Linoff      |
+----+------------+-------------+
```

It's a table contains my website's users. Now I want to search in them. What's your query suggestion?

---

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users 
WHERE first_name LIKE :input%
   OR last_name LIKE :input%
   OR CONCAT(first_name, last_name) LIKE :input%
```

As you can see, my query just searches, nothing else. There isn't any `ORDER BY` clause, so no priority defined. You know, all I'm trying to do is implementing something like this search engine:

[image]

Anyway does anybody how can I implement a priority to my query? For example, if you search `Koop`, the first row of the result should be the second row in the table, because `last_name` column should has a bigger priority *(than `first_name` column)* and `koop` is the exact value of `last_name` for the second row of the table.

Here is the expected result for `:input = 'koop'`:

```
+----+------------+-------------+
| 2  | Martin     | Koop        |
| 1  | John       | Kooper      |
| 3  | Koop       | Sth         |
+----+------------+-------------+
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Full text search might help here.  By the way, who is Jack Linoff ^ ^ ?

Comment: (1) you have a typo in your query: `last_name LIKR` and (2) you can use `ORDER BY` to order the results and (3) the "priority" that you see on SO is based on the reputation of that user. Find an external source to sort your data (eg other column or join another table).

Comment: I think your question is "How do identify a relevance of a search result based on arbitrary criteria. The answer is, 1. identify your criteria for relevance, 2. implement it!  If you get stuck, come let us know

Answer (score 1):

Consider to use FULLTEXT search.

```
SELECT *,
    MATCH (`first_name`) AGAINST (':input*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS `relevance_first_name`,
    MATCH (`last_name`) AGAINST (':input*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS `relevance_last_name`
FROM `users`
WHERE MATCH (`first_name`, `last_name`) AGAINST (':input*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY (`relevance_first_name`)+(`relevance_last_name`*4) DESC
```

Comment: seems good, thank you. upvote. Just may you please tell me why did you use `IN BOOLEAN MODE` ?

Comment: To search as a wildecard :input* - asterisk(*)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ORDER BY` columns...
For example, you can sort first by last name, then by first name.

```
SELECT u.* FROM users 
    WHERE first_name LIKE :input%
        OR last_name LIKR :input%
        OR CONCAT(first_name, last_name) LIKE :input%
    ORDER BY last_name, first_name;
```

**Update**
From your comments, if you want to sort by priority, which is rating or anything else, you should user `ORDER BY users._column_name` or join another table where rating column is, and order the result by this column.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution could be a (switch) case statement inside the order by clause like this:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users 
WHERE first_name LIKE :input%
OR last_name LIKE :input%
OR CONCAT(first_name, last_name) LIKE :input%     
ORDER BY 
(CASE WHEN first_name = :input THEN 1 
      WHEN first_name LIKE :input% THEN 2 (....) ELSE 99 END) ;
```